# asp.net mvc + wordpress on IIS 8 on same root

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, fastcgi

Is it possible to run wordpress and asp.net mvc site on the same root. My client want that and I asked him to install wordpress blog in a sub directory but he insisted to do it on the same root because he claims he has seen running both together without sub directory.

I have deleted the default route for mvc site from route.config. And installed the wordpress from Plesk panel and setup it's permalinks. Now wordpress is working fine, but asp.net mvc routes are not working.

I am aware IIS use FastCGI to rewrite the routes for wordpress. Is there any way that asp.net mvc routes also work?

Please help me out, Thanks